# How to simulate a 3D Electromagnetic field

Tags: modeling

Anyone knows how to simulate an electromagnetic field in 3D?
Thank you guys

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add more information to understand what you are trying to do. Are you looking to create an image with that kind of gradient or are you looking for an interactive model?

Comment: I have a spherical (or rod shape) magnet, and hope to view the magnetic field around it. Just the image is fine.

Comment: I am using cycles engine

Comment: Hum at first sight I don't think this is going to be very easy to make, since it seems to be seem sort of volumetric effect but outside the shape around the mesh volume; and displayed as sort of a 2D bidimensional effect. Maybe with some inverted normal trickery? Not sure

Comment: To me, this seems like it could be easy enough to solve with python scriptING and volumetric rendering. Python to perform the simulation, volumes to display it

Comment: could you please make a brief tutorial on how to achieve that?

Comment: Let me link this answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/52240/7777.  GiantCowFilms is right.