# How to make a neodymium magnet?

Tags: modeling, force-fields

I am new in Blender and would like to make two [neodymium magnets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neodymium_magnet) that simulate the forces and attraction, but I have no idea how to make it.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/52240/7777